# Access to service properties in service consumer ( iPOJO )

Tags: osgi, ipojo

In iPOJO, is there any way to read service properties (e.g. getProperty(key) ) in service consumer?
The publisher is pretty straight forward but, in consumer seems I can only use filter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use callbacks to retrieve service properties:

```
@Bind
public void bindService(HelloService hello, Dictionary<String, Object> properties) {
      // ...
}
```

or

```
@Bind
public void bindService(HelloService hello, Map<String, Object> properties) {
  // ...
}
```

You can even retrieve the OSGi service registration:

```
@Bind
public void bindService(HelloService hello, ServiceReference<HelloService> reference) {
  // ...
}
```

All details are on http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/describing-components/service-requirement-handler.html#note-about-callbacks

Comment: Thanks, that is cool also, I can detect if a property has been changed or not:         @Modified
           public void modifiedService(HelloService hello, Map<String, Object> properties) {
  // ...
}